# connect to remote osgi container using -Dosgi.console vm arg

Tags: eclipse-plugin, console, osgi

I am trying to access the osgi console of eclipse container in remote machine which is used to run automated test suites. We use ant to run the unit tests in test agents. Below is the ant taks we are using.
I found out that i need to add this command line argument to make the remote agent listen to the port specified."-Dosgi.console=8005". I ran the script but it is not stopping saying"listening to 8005". i was able to successfully remote debug this agent but i need osgi console view to debug the bundles that got installed in the agent.
Did i place the argument in the correct position? Does it have to be in any order?
Any help is appreciated. i do not understand why it never worked.

```
<java dir="${basedir}" classname="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main" fork="true" classpathref="equinox.launcher.class.path">
<arg line="-application org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication -data ${tempWorkspace} -dev bin -testlistener org.eclipse.test.XMLTestListener -clean -port ${pde.test.port} -testpluginname ${testrunner.plugin.name} -classnames ${master.testsuite.name}"/>
<jvmarg value="-Xbootclasspath/a:${project.root}/lib/External/Clover/clover.jar"/>
<jvmarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" />
<jvmarg value="-Xms512m"/>
<jvmarg value="-Xmx1280m"/>
<jvmarg value="-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.http.port=2910"/>
<jvmarg value="-Dxcp.builder.testsuite.testplugins=xxxx.tests"/>
<jvmarg value="-Dosgi.console=8005"/>
<jvmarg value="-Xdebug"/>
<jvmarg value="-Xnoagent"/>
<jvmarg value="-Djava.compiler=NONE"/>
<jvmarg value="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Equinox 3.8 or newer, you must use the -Dosgi.console.enable.builtin=true system property as well. See http://hwellmann.blogspot.hu/2012/08/new-osgi-console-in-equinox-380.html

Comment: Thanks. It still does not not work. When i run my testsuite locally in my test ide it works. But if i run them in a test agent it does not work. I see that tycho compile log says the plugin that i am looking is compiled fine and built. But for some reason one of the tests plugin is not loaded and i am trying to debug why but without this console view it is hard to tell whether that bundle is installed or not. Do i need to have those gogo plugins in my test environment? Because i had to include them in my launch config to get -console working in my eclipse ide!

Answer (score 0):

To launch the new OSGi console in Eclipse, you need to ensure that the console bundle and its dependencies are available. These include:

- org.eclipse.equinox.console
- org.apache.felix.gogo.shell
- org.apache.felix.gogo.command
- org.apache.felix.gogo.shell

Since it's unlikely your code has any dependencies on these they won't be installed into your test runtime, and therefore won't be available for starting the console.